# Difficulty modeling Star schema

Tags: database-design, business-intelligence, star-schema, multi-database, datamart

I am creating a fact table which will measure the amount of resources related to schools:

```
Amount of Schools
Amount of Students
Amount of Employees
Amount of computers (for administrative use and students use)

FACT_SCHOOL_RESOURCES
    School (FK)
    Location (FK)
    Education Type (FK)
    Total_Schools (every line has value 1)
    Total_Students
    Total_Employees
    Total_Students_Computers
    Total_Administration_Computers
```

There are some infrastructure issues that are related to schools, which I can't actually put as one of its attributes (an attribute named `infrastructure`) because there are more than one type (Energy Source, Water Source, Waste Disposal...) and I can't use each type as an attribute, because for each type, I have a many-to-many relationship with my school dimension. For example:

```
Power Source
    Solar Panel
    Generator
    City Energy Supply
    ...   
Waste Disposal
    Landfill
    Incineration
    Recycling
    Composting
    Waste to Energy
    ...
```

Using these examples, a school can have both Landfill and Recycling as its waste disposal or make use of the City Energy Supply at the same time as a Generator or Solar Panels.

All of this is necessary because studies show that some of these issues (and many others) are related to teaching quality and there should be a way to analyse it all.

How do I solve this on a star schema?

Comment: This is an old post but for those that find it: This is way too broad. You are asking for a textbook plus tutorial plus bespoke example. Follow a published method & ask 1 specific reserached non-duplicate question re how/why you are 1st stuck. [ask] [Help]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you are looking for something that goes beyond star schema.  If you want to do some multi-variant analysis on which factors are most strongly correlated with some metric (e.g. teaching quality) then you might need to consider a cube.

Treat the presence of each of the types of power source and waste disposal as an attribute.  Perhaps you can start with something as simple as binary flags for each factor.  You can then test for correlation between your metric and your factors with different slices in the cube.

Comment: thanks for replying. I think I get what you are saying about the flags. But that would mean a huge fact table (because, believe me, there are a lot of "infrastructure variables") with a lot of atributes (fk) such as "Solar Panel" or "Recycling" and each of theses dimensions would only have it's ID and the Binary flag that would determine if they "Have solar panels", "Recycle their trash", "Have a generator"...?

Comment: The only things I didn't get is, If I make my star schema, eventualy, after creating my Semantic Layer, wouldn't I end up with a cube? Or a cube is a very different thing?

Comment: @LeonardoSibela Star schema is a relational database construct for supporting BI/data warehouse style data access.  You can also approximate a cube in a relational database as well, however, there are non-RDBMS tools that make manipulating data in cubes easier.  All of the major RDBMS vendors support specialized cube databases and queries.  Depending on your platform, you can look into what is available to you.

Answer (score -1):

RDBMS you start will a million pieces and aggregate them to where you want, cubes you start with one piece and tear it apart to where you want, basically you end up with the same answer, just depends if you roll up or drill down :)